# On some prime non-divisors of polynomials' resultant

Tags: nt.number-theory

Do there exist infinitely many primes $q = 1 \mod p$ where $p$ is some prime, such that $q \nmid R((x^{\frac{q-1}{p}}-1), (x+1)^{\frac{q-1}{p}}-1)$, where $R(u, v)$ denotes the resultant of the polynomials $u(x), v(x)$ ?

Comment: I think $q$ dividing that resultant says there is a pair of consecutive $p$-power residues modulo $q$, and I think that for every $p$ there are such residues for all $q$ sufficiently large. So I think the answer is, no.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, thanks.  But aren't you referring to the case when $q$ divides the resultant ? Notice that we have $q \nmid R(u, v)$ in the question.

Comment: Yes. I'm suggesting that $q$ dividing the resultant is equivalent to the existence of consecutive $p$-power residues, and that the existence of such residues is guaranteed for $q$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Okay thanks. But in the question, $q$ does not divide the resultant, so how does this address the question ? Sorry if I'm missing something "obvious".

Comment: I think you have to step back and reread what I've written, carefully.

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted a couple of days ago, 149257?

Comment: Are you still here, 149257?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p,q$ be primes with $q\equiv1\bmod p$. Suppose there exists $a$ such that $a$ and $a+1$ are both $p$th powers modulo $q$. Then $a$ is a common root of the polynomials $f(x)=x^{(q-1)/p}-1$ and $g(x)=(x+1)^{(q-1)/p}-1$ over the field of $q$ elements. Thus, the resultant of $f$ and $g$ is zero in that field, that is, it is a multiple of $q$.

Now let $p$ be fixed. We have established that if for all sufficiently large $q\equiv1\bmod p$ there exists $a$ such that $a$ and $a+1$ are both $p$th powers modulo $q$, then there are at most finitely many $q\equiv1\bmod p$ such that $q$ does not divide the resultant; in other words, we will have the answer "No" to the posted question.

A. E. Pellet, Mémoire sur la théorie algébrique des équations, Bull. Soc. Math. France 15 (1887) 61-102, showed that for every prime $p$ there is a number $q_0(p)$ such that if $q$ is prime and $q\ge q_0(p)$ then $x^p+y^p+z^p\equiv0\bmod q$ has nontrivial solutions. (Later authors found explicit values for $q_0(p)$, and slicker proofs than that of Pellet, but it does appear that Pellet was the first one to get a result). Divide through by $x^p$ to get $u^p\equiv1+v^p\bmod q$ where $u\equiv-z/x\bmod q$ and $v\equiv y/x\bmod q$. Then we can take $a=v^p$, and we have both $a$ and $a+1\equiv u^p\bmod q$ are $p$th powers modulo $q$, and we're done.